# SwiftyJson when integrating google maps

Tags: ios, swift

Do we have to separately download and add swiftyJson when integrating Google Maps with for iOS?

Comment: please explain more.

Comment: I want to serialize a json file when integrating Google maps. I just wanted to know whether SwiftJson Library already added when installing Google maps SDK?

Comment: you need to add seperatly

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't come with google maps sdk, you have to install it separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your googleMap & swiftjson framework on same podfle .

Answer (score 0):

Add both file using **Cocoa Pods** concept

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
# use_frameworks! 

target 'Your Project Name' do

  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'SwiftyJson'

end
```

if get error uncomment this - **use_frameworks**